# When I export video from Final Cut Pro, how to set the export directory?

Tags: macos, final-cut-pro

This is my video I edit in Final Cut Pro, but I don't know where to set the export place when I share my video. If I share it, I don't know where to find my exported video.

[image]

[image]

---

**Add information**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sharing methods have a default action.

If that is set to `Add to playlist:` then it will simply put it into your appropriate media folder in your user folder. Many sharing methods have this as the default.

If you set that to `Do Nothing`, then the `Share` button will turn to `Next...` indicating that it will ask you where you want to Export the media to when you click that. For Example:

[image: Add to playlist]

or...

[image: Do Nothing]

Comment: thanks very much, I got you, can I ask a question, how to set the video format when share? the default is `.m4v`, I want to set `.mov`

Comment: The Apple Devices format is an MPEG-4 wrapped around H.264. You'll want to change the Format to "Video and Audio" and you'll get a list of codec options (you can still use H.264) but the wrapper will be a Quicktime Movie (.mov).

Comment: but the video size will be very large.

Comment: If you really want to get fine control of an export, you want to be utilizing Compressor. Instead of the "Share" option in the File menu, use the "Send to Compressor" option. Then right-click the closest BUILT-IN export option to what you're trying to do and Duplicate it. You can then get fine control of exact settings on the right side. All the things you can do with Compressor are way too vast to get into here, but suffice it to say, you can make it as close to the original or as compressed as you want. In your case, I recommend starting with "Video Sharing Services -> HD 720p"

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got that, use shortcut key： <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, to open in the finder:

[image]

Then open the `Share Items`, then I can find the result:

[image]